# Objective C Leaks when releasing objects with UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I am running the following code in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
File *file = [[File alloc] init];
file = [self.fileList objectAtIndex:row];
UIImage* theImage = file.fileIconImage;

cell.imageView.image = theImage;
cell.textLabel.text = file.fileName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = file.fileModificationDate;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
```

I ran the leaks tool and found out that the File object is leaking because I am not releasing it.  So I added the release prior to returning the cell where I thought it was safe (as shown below):

```
File *file = [[File alloc] init];
file = [self.fileList objectAtIndex:row];

UIImage* theImage = file.fileIconImage;

cell.imageView.image = theImage;
cell.textLabel.text = file.fileName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = file.fileModificationDate;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
[file release];

return cell;
```

Now, when I run the application it crashes.  Are the UITableViewCells still referencing the file object?  What is the approach to use here to make sure I am not leaking memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
File *file = [[File alloc] init];
file = [self.fileList objectAtIndex:row];
```

Well, here you're first allocating a new `File` and then you discard the pointer and apparently get another existing object from an array. That's the one you release if you call `release` later on. The one you call `release` on in the end is not the one you allocated. The pointer to the freshly allocated one is lost and thus leaks.

Probably it crashes because `self.fileList` contains a pointer to an already destructed object thereafter.

Maybe you meant to write just

```
File *file = [self.fileList objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: Fair, hadn't looked at that bit, had only suggested the autorelease with the alloc/init... but you're right, he doesn't need to alloc/init the file object at all!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the cell is still referencing it at the point you are releasing it, so the app crashes.

You need to use autorelease when you declare it, as follows:

```
File *file = [[[File alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Then, don't call the [file release] part.  As soon as it's not referenced any more (ie when you stop using the cell) it will be autoreleased at the start of the next run loop.